# Explanation of how Git checkout works

Tags: git

I am using the default bash that comes with Git, I made a master branch (not bare) and made a branch (lets call it new_feature branch) out of it.

I am playing around with branching and I get to the point where I am testing the `git checkout` command. As I have understood, the checkout command allows switching from one branch to another. Also from what I understood, the checkout command doesn't allow you to switch from one branch to another if the working directory is dirty (i.e. has unstaged edits).

Now I have a file named `index.html` in both my main branch and my feature branch. Both the files in the 2 branches have exactly the same content. Now here is what I did, and it made me confused.

I am on my feature branch (currently both files have exact same content now), if I edit the content of `index.html`, say the title tag, and I did not staged it, if I issue the command `git checkout master`, Git does allow me to switch to the master branch, and what's more interesting is that if I issue the `git status` command within the master branch, the unstaged changes I made on the feature branch gets copied to the master branch. Isn't it destructive?

What made me more confused is, in a given time where the 2 files on both the branches, master and feature branch, doesn't have the same content, if I'm inside the feature branch and edit the content of the `index.html` file, say the title tag, now if I issue the `git checkout master` command, it don't allow me to make the switch because it detected that my working tree or directory is dirty.

Bottom line, as I have noticed based on these events, if 2 files have the same content, if you are in one branch, modify the content of that file, and checkout to that other branch, Git allows you to make the switch, and Git carries the unstaged changes you made to that destination branch.

But if 2 files on 2 different branches have different content, if you are on one branch, made the edit to that file, and issue the checkout command to switch to that other branch, Git doesn't allow you to make the switch because for some reason it detects that the working tree is dirty.

Is my understanding correct or wrong? Also I can use a little explanation as to why my understanding is wrong or correct.

Comment: I capitalized your sentences and fixed your spelling for you. "Coz" is not technically a real word, even though it's a hip mis-spelling and abbreviation for "because".

Comment: @Cupcake I respectfully suggest that JPlus2 is capable of deciding for him/herself on her/his desired level of formality and correctness. Your going in ten minutes later and "correcting" the text strikes me as, well, rude and, frankly, arrogant. (Yes, I do realize that I am exposing myself to a similar charge :P )  A comment explaining that he/she would be more likely to be taken more seriously and thus have a better chance at receiving a good answer, and suggesting that she/he edit the question him/herself with that in mind, would have been more appropriate, IMHO. Cheers.

Comment: [SLaks has the right answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18690485/1256452), but it might help if you think of git as letting you carry a change you started "before" you realized you were on the wrong branch, over to the right branch, by doing "git checkout".  Personally I think this would be less confusing if it were a different command (e.g., `git oops-forgot-to-switch-branch-earlier-do-it-now-if-safe`), but it *is* quite safe, it's just a bit surprising at first that it lets you do that.

Comment: @Edward I respectfully disagree, these questions don't just serve the original poster, they also serve anyone else on the internet as well. Therefore, proper English is a requirement. You don't own your content on Stack Overflow, the community does, and anyone has the right to edit content if it helps improve it.

Comment: @Cupcake Apologies, just starting out with stack overflow also. thanks for the reminder

torek, Thanks for the answer, really helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unstaged changes are not part of git at all.
`git checkout` has no effect on any files that are not in git (whether they are unstaged changes or gitignored files).

To prevent data loss, `git checkout` will give an error if it needs to change a file with unstaged changes.

In other words, if you have two branches with different versions of a file, and you edit that file, then try to switch to the other branch, you will get an error because it will refuse to replace your unstaged changes with the other branch's version.

Comment: Also should probably mention that the checkout isn't "destructive" per se because the unstaged code haven't been checked in on either branch. It's implied and is obvious once you understand it but the OP was worried that the feature branch was clobbering his master branch when in fact no such thing actually happened.

Comment: Exactly what I meant slebetman, I was worried if my feature branch was clobbering my master branch. Thanks for the reply.

@Slasks, thank you for the answer, I somehow now get what you mean, one last thing though, why did git allow me to switch branch if my index.html file on both feature and master branch contents are the same, and I edit the index.html on feature branch and I switch to master, why git allowed that? thats the thing I am most confused of, apologies for the hassle.

Comment: @Jplus2: Because they're the same, switching branches has no effect on that file.  Therefore, git ignores your unstaged changes.  In particular, until you `git commit`, your changes aren't on any branch.